# Is there a way to download a sample CSV file

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv, assign

I used a sample of a csv program to do some tables on Jupiter notebook, I now need to download that sample csv file so I can look at it in excel, is there a way I can download the sample

I need to download lf if possible.

Here is my code:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests 

df = pd.read_csv("diamonds.csv")

lf = df.sample(5000, random_state=999)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline 
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
plt.style.use("seaborn")

lf.sample(5000, random_state=999)'''
```

Comment: Where is 'diamonds.csv' located?

Comment: to_csv('df.csv') will export it from a pandas dataframe to sv local file

Answer (score 2):

You first need to convert the sample to a dataframe and then you can export it.

```
dframe.to_csv(“file_name.csv”)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: i also have noticed some beforementioned posts and just have accessing to file through made simple FTP petitions for CSV Download.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http):

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://jupyter.com/diamond.csv", "diamond.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

if what you mean by download is exporting the dataframe to spreadsheet format, pandas have the function

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("diamond.csv")
# do your stuff
df.to_csv("diamond2.csv") # if you want to export to csv with different name
df.to_csv("folder/diamond2.csv") # if you want to export to csv inside existed folder
df.to_excel("diamond2.xlsx") # if you want to export to excel
```

The file will appear on the same directory as your jupyter notebook.

You can also specify the directory

```py
df.to_csv('D:/folder/diamond.csv')
```

to check where is your current work directory, you can use

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```